# How change font size dynamically when scrollView contentOffset y changed?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, swift3

I have `UIScrollView` and `UILabel`. I want to change `UILabel` size dynamically from 33.0 to 0.0 , 0.0 to 33 when user scroll up / down my `UIScrollView`.

How can I do this?

```
@IBOutlet weak var myLabel : UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    scrollView.delegate = self
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let fontpointmath = (myLabel.font.pointSize / (offset / 100) - 15)

    if offset > 0 {
        if fontpointmath < 0 {
            myLabel.font =  UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 0.0)
        }else if fontpointmath > 33 {
            myLabel.font =  UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 33.0)
        }else{
            myLabel.font =  UIFont(name: "Arial", size: CGFloat(fontpointmath))
        }
    }
```

My current code only allow font size to about 15 points and doesn't change to 0. It also doesn't go up to 33 when user scroll down again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try to use transform instead font size changing

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    scrollView.delegate = self
    myLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 33.0)
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let scale = min(max(1.0 - offset / 200.0, 0.0), 1.0)
    myLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
}
```

Comment: How to make reverse effect. My requirement is to change font size 0 to 33.