# Change label's font size dynamically when scrolling tableView

Tags: swift, scroll, label, font-size

I have tableView and on top of it an imageView. Made stretchable header with this guide https://github.com/abhimuralidharan/StretchableTableViewHeader-Swift
And now I have to add label on my image. This label should change size/font when tableView is scrolling.

I created my imageView in another class:

```
class LotteryHeaderView: UIImageView {

let ticketsCountLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.textColor = .white
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 100)
    return label
}()

let infoLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.textColor = .white
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13, weight: .medium)
    label.numberOfLines = 2
    label.text = Localizable.all_user_tickets_count()
    return label
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.addSubViews([ticketsCountLabel, infoLabel])

    ticketsCountLabel.centerX(to: self.centerXAnchor)
        .centerY(to: self.centerYAnchor)

    infoLabel.top(to: ticketsCountLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 7)
        .width(constant: 184)
        .centerX(to: self.centerXAnchor)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

Initialized it in my controller:

```
let imageView = LotteryHeaderView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: Constants.Size.screenWidth, height: 300))
```

Setup in viewDidLoad:

```
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: Constants.Size.screenWidth, height: 300)
    imageView.image = R.image.santa_fe()
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    view.addSubview(imageView)
```

Here func which gets called every time the tableview is scrolled, and it works for my image (it collapsable and stretchable):

```
func scrollImageInHeader(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let y = 300 - (scrollView.contentOffset.y + 300)
    let height = min(max(y, 60), 450)
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: Constants.Size.screenWidth, height: height)
}
```

Tried to add in scrollImageInHeader() code under, from [this StackOverFlowAnswer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41186530/how-change-font-size-dynamically-when-scrollview-contentoffset-y-changed), but it doesn't help

```
let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let scale = min(max(1.0 - offset / 200.0, 0.0), 1.0)
    imageView.ticketsCountLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
```

Please, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found my mistake. Code from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41186530/how-change-font-size-dynamically-when-scrollview-contentoffset-y-changed) helped.
Class LotteryHeaderView I changed to UIView and added there an UIImageView.

Answer (score 0):

UIScrollView is parent UITableViewController.  You use UIScrollView with UIScrollViewDelegate for setup label font size with scrollOffset: CGFloat follow .y

```
extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate{
  func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    var scrollOffset : CGFloat = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    // process with scrollOffset
  }
}
```